# Upload to App Store disabled in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, application-loader

"Upload to App Store" is disabled in xCode.  The Archive Type is "iOS App Archive".  The provisioning profile is "Xcode Managed Profile" and the info pop up for it has everything checked. The app in iTunes Connect is configured and waiting.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9gAEpJAcaKDQVFfbzhRRnhKUkk/view?usp=sharing

Can't use Application Loader either since the Export button is disabled as well.

Comment: Are you enrolled in the Apple Developer Program? Xcode doesn't seem to think so.